# Comparison expression inside Promise always return true

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm learning about Promise in Javascript. But when I tried to write some lines of code, I have this problem. My "if" statement, which I declare inside a Promise Obj always return true. Here's information:

- Environment: Chrome Dev Tools - Chrome Dev Tools - Chromium 64.0.3282.140
- Code:

```js
var status = false;
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  if (status) {
    console.log("TRUE")
    resolve({
      value: 'true'
    });
  } else {
    console.log("FALSE");
    reject({
      value: 'false'
    });
  }
});
```

- Expected output: FALSE
- What happened instead: TRUE
- **Notice**: whatever the value of "status" is, the output always true.
  I'm really looking for an explanation for my problem here. Thank you so much.

Comment: Incidentally, excellent first question! As an aside, typically you should only reject promises with an Error `reject(new Error('false'))`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`status` is a predefined variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/status) in browsers.

When you assign a value to it, it is cast to a string.

`false` becomes `"false"` which is a true value.

This is why you should avoid globals. Conflicts with other people's variables are never fun.

---

Wrap your code in an IIFE to avoid trying to create variables in the global scope.

```js
(function() {

  var status = false;
  var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    if (status) {
      console.log("TRUE")
      resolve({
        value: 'true'
      });
    } else {
      console.log("FALSE");
      reject({
        value: 'false'
      });
    }
  });

}());
```

Comment: Another option, is not to use var.  block level  `const` `let` will also fix this.  But avoiding global's should be top priority anyway.